# Kindle app not finding all files

Tags: epub, mobi, kindle-app

I have several epub and mobi ebooks on my Andriod phone. The Kindle app finds about half of them. I went to settings->local file access and unchecked and rechecked each folder where the ebooks are located. That may have added a few ebooks, but not the ones I'm currently interested in. I think that several months ago, Kindle found and listed all my ebooks, so maybe the current Kindle app has a bug in it. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: What format are the ebooks? I think Kindle has been phasing out mobi format ebooks, at least via their "send to kindle" service, and it may be that they've removed support from their apps as well. You may need to use [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert the files to azw format.

Comment: I have both mobi and epub formats. I'll try the azw format and see if Kindle recognizes it.

Comment: Update: I converted 4 of my epubs to azw3, and Kindle found all of them! Thanks for the tip!